# Why am I getting column headers for each index of a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi so currently I am trying to create an empty dataframe in python using this code:

```
for i in range (len('bus0')):
    empty_df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[i], columns=['bus0', 'bus1'])
    print(empty_df)
```

But I am getting an output (below) which reprints the column headers bus0 and bus1 for each index in the dataframe:

```
 bus0  bus1
0   NaN   NaN
   bus0  bus1
1   NaN   NaN
   bus0  bus1
2   NaN   NaN
   bus0  bus1
3   NaN   NaN
```

I do not want the column headers to keep reappearing for each index, I just want them to show up once at the top. How does one achieve this?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve for your end goal?

Comment: On each iteration of the loop you're creating a brand new DataFrame with 1 row indexed at the current iteration and printing it. Do you just want a DataFrame of NaN's in the shape (4,2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on.  You're both reassigning and reprinting the dataframe every time you go through the for loop.

To see what I mean, the following code (just taking the print statement out of the for loop) only prints the last data assigned to the dataframe.

```
for i in range (len('bus0')):
    empty_df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[i], columns=['bus0', 'bus1'])

# print(empty_df)
'''
bus0  bus1
3   NaN   NaN
'''
```

Instead of reassigning the whole dataframe, I would declare it before the for loop and just add each row in the for loop using [.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).  You can also use .iloc to assign different values to different rows while iterating through the for loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['bus0', 'bus1'])

for i in range (len('bus0')):
    empty_df.loc[i] = np.nan

# print(empty_df)
'''
bus0 bus1
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
'''
```

Comment: Thanks Colin, this is exactly what I was looking for! Appreciate you taking the time to go step by step.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

array = np.asarray([np.nan for x in range(8)]).reshape((4,2))

df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=['bus0', 'bus1'])
```